# issue route configuration in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

here is my route I have config:

```
$route['price_list'] = 'Price/index';
$route['price_list/(:any)'] = 'Price/index/$1';
```

then I create menu on the view, let's say I have a link like this :

```
<a href="price_list/company?id=1">.....</a>
<a href="price_list/company?id=2">.....</a>
```

when I click with the first it work, but when I click it again it will return me with link duplicate price_list:

```
<a href="price_list/price_list/company?id=...">......</a>
```

please help me ! thank !!!

Comment: Did you hard code the links or it's filled by the PHP

Comment: I'm not sour with your command. is my coding is not fill by php

Comment: show your code here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href ="<?php echo site_url("price_list/company?id=1"); ?>">......</a>
```

OR

```
<a href ="<?php echo base_url("price_list/company?id=1"); ?>">......</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `base_url()` in your anchor tag like below

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>price_list/company?id=2">.....</a>
```

And make sure you've added `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`in your `autoload.php` file